# Angular 7 ng-pick-datetime with ngModel wrong locale

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular4-forms

I've been struggling with the problem for weeks when the picker binds the value of my model using wrong locale, so when it tries to show day >12 as month it shows empty textbox. My locale is ru-RU and date format is `dd-MM-yyyy`.

My picker inside update form:

```
<owl-date-time name="exploitation_date"
#exploitation_date="ngModel"
class="form-control form-control-ufo"
[placeHolder]="'DD.MM.YYYY'"
[locale]="ru_locale"
[(ngModel)]="model.exploitation_date"
[type]="'calendar'"
[dataType]="'string'"
[dateFormat]="'DD.MM.YYYY'"
[readonlyInput]="false" 
[inputId]="'exploitation_date'"
required>
</owl-date-time>
```

The model:

```
export class Example{
    exploitation_date:string;
    ...
}
```

The component:

```
 this.ru_locale = {
        firstDayOfWeek: 1,
        dayNames: ['Воскресенье'..],
        monthNames: ['Январь', 'Февраль'...],
        monthNamesShort: ['Янв', 'Фев'...]
    };
```

Saving picked value works fine,the only issue is to display existing date in textbox.

Angular version 7.1
ng-pick-datetime: "^5.0.0-beta.11"

I thought about the update of `ng-pick-datetime`, but afraid I'll face the same problem. I tried to set `moment` locale but it didn't help.